# さえ vs でさえ ｜ この整理は正しいですか。(English available)

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-さえ

## 日本語

**以下の整理は正しいですか。正しくないところがあれば、てつだってください。**

---

### １　「でさえ」の「で」は助詞の「で」の場合

> X: 世界の闇｛やみ｝の中**さえ**きっとあなたは輝｛かがや｝く。
>   **O:** 世界の闇の中**でさえ**きっとあなたは輝く。

闇の中**で**輝く -> 闇の中**でさえ**輝く
元の助詞は「で」ですよね。「**さえ**」が入るなら、「で」は「**でさえ**」になります。「で」は消せません。

> **O:** 君**さえ**止められない人間を見たことがない。
>   I've never seen someone who couldn't stop even you.
>
> **O:** 君**でさえ**止められない人間を見たことがない。
>   I've never seen someone whom even you couldn't stop.
>
> (from broccoli forest’s answer in [ですら・でも・さえ・だろう（と／が）。 Are there any differences?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19784/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%82%89-%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82-%E3%81%95%E3%81%88-%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86-%E3%81%A8-%E3%81%8C-are-there-any-differences/19792#19792))

「君**さえ**」の文章は、最初に「君が」ですから、「が」が消えます。broccoli forest によると、「君**さえ**止められない」は「人間が君を止めることができない」ということです。

「君**でさえ**」の文章は、状態の「で」ですから　（君として止められない）、「で」が消えなくて、「さえ」が入ります。broccoli forest によれば、「君**でさえ**止められない」は「君が人間を止めることができない」ということです。
(子供でわからなければ、大人に聞くといい。[さえ how to use it](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33409/%E3%81%95%E3%81%88-how-to-use-it))

---

### ２　「でさえ」の「で」は「である」の「で」の場合

その場合は、「さえ」と「でさえ」の用法はわからない時、まず「条件」か「類推」か考えたほうがいいと思います。

> **条件**
>   **O:** お金**さえ**あれば、いいですね。
>   X: お金**でさえ**あれば、いいですね。
>
> **O:** パソコン**さえ**あれば、仕事ができる。
>   X: パソコン**でさえ**あれば、仕事ができる。
>
> **O:** あの男**さえ**いなくなれば。。。
>   X: あの男**でさえ**いなくなれば。。。
>
> **類推**
>   X: この問題、猿**さえ**解けますよ。
>   **O:** この問題、猿**でさえ**解けますよ。
>
> X: 犯人**さえ**人情{にんじょう}がありますよ。世界の闇**さえ**輝ける。
>   **O:** 犯人**でさえ**人情がありますよ。世界の闇**でさえ**輝ける。

---

**脚｛きゃく｝注｛ちゅう｝**

[さえ how to use it](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33409/%E3%81%95%E3%81%88-how-to-use-it)

[ですら・でも・さえ・だろう（と／が）。 Are there any differences?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19784/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%82%89-%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82-%E3%81%95%E3%81%88-%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86-%E3%81%A8-%E3%81%8C-are-there-any-differences/19792#19792)

[Difference between さえ、でさえ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36397/difference-between-%E3%81%95%E3%81%88-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%95%E3%81%88/36407#36407)

[での用法](http://okwave.jp/qa/q8538191.html)

(Edited errors involving particles and translation)

## English

Are the following observations correct? Please help if I have made mistakes somewhere.

---

### １　When で in「でさえ」is a particle

> X: 世界の闇｛やみ｝の中**さえ**きっとあなたは輝｛かがや｝く。
>   **O:** 世界の闇の中**でさえ**きっとあなたは輝く。
>   Even in the darkness of the world, you will surely shine.

闇の中**で**輝く becomes 闇の中**でさえ**輝く.  Since あなた shines **in** the darkness, で is needed to express a place of action.
At first で is used, but once **さえ** is added, で doesn't disappear; it becomes **でさえ**.

> **O:** 君**さえ**止められない人間を見たことがない。
>   I've never seen someone who couldn't stop even you.
>
> **O:** 君**でさえ**止められない人間を見たことがない。
>   I've never seen someone whom even you couldn't stop.
>
> (from broccoli forest’s answer in [ですら・でも・さえ・だろう（と／が）。 Are there any differences?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19784/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%82%89-%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82-%E3%81%95%E3%81%88-%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86-%E3%81%A8-%E3%81%8C-are-there-any-differences/19792#19792))

For 君**さえ**, the original phrase is 君が, but が disappears. According to broccoli forest, 君**さえ**止められない means「人間が君を止めることができない」- the subject is a human, 人間, and the object is 君.

For 君**でさえ**, the「で」is a particle that expresses a state - the state of being 君（like saying 君として止められない - **As** you, you cannot stop...）. で doesn't disappear when さえ enters. broccoli forest says again, 君**でさえ**止められない means「君が人間を止めることができない」.
(A similar sentence would be 子供でわからなければ、大人に聞くといい。from [さえ how to use it](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33409/%E3%81%95%E3%81%88-how-to-use-it))

---

### ２　When で in「でさえ」is from「である」

In this case, I think it's best to think about whether a condition or an analogy is being expressed.

> **Condition**
>   **O:** お金**さえ**あれば、いいですね。
>   X: お金**でさえ**あれば、いいですね。
>   If only I have money; that would be great.
>
> **O:** パソコン**さえ**あれば、仕事ができる。
>   X: パソコン**でさえ**あれば、仕事ができる。
>   If only I had a computer; I would be able to do my work.
>
> **O:** あの男**さえ**いなくなれば。。。
>   X: あの男**でさえ**いなくなれば。。。
>   If only that man weren't there...
>
> **Analogy**
>   X: この問題、猿**さえ**解けますよ。
>   **O:** この問題、猿**でさえ**解けますよ。
>   Even a monkey can solve this question.
>
> X: 犯人**さえ**人情{にんじょう}がありますよ。世界の闇**さえ**輝ける。
>   **O:** 犯人**でさえ**人情がありますよ。世界の闇**でさえ**輝ける。
>   Even a criminal has humanity, you know. Even the darkness in the world can shine.

---

**References**

[さえ how to use it](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33409/%E3%81%95%E3%81%88-how-to-use-it)

[ですら・でも・さえ・だろう（と／が）。 Are there any differences?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19784/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%82%89-%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82-%E3%81%95%E3%81%88-%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86-%E3%81%A8-%E3%81%8C-are-there-any-differences/19792#19792)

[Difference between さえ、でさえ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36397/difference-between-%E3%81%95%E3%81%88-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%95%E3%81%88/36407#36407)

[での用法](http://okwave.jp/qa/q8538191.html)

(Edited errors involving particles and translation)

Comment: この問題、猿さえ解けますよ and 犯人さえ人情がありますよ are correct.

Comment: Would 猿でさえ be more grammatical since この問題、猿さえ解けますよ。 tends to imply "This question can solve even monkeys?" Or is there no difference in this case?

Comment: They mean "even monkeys can solve this question" and "even the culprit has sympathy".

Comment: In the first place, all the examples are technically possible but just some don't make good sense including usage of は or が (though I understand it's tough to you considering how you wrote「でさえ」の「で」は「である」の「で」の場合). For example, only using は like 世界の闇の中さえきっとあなた は 輝く can make it not so nonsensical.

Comment: I think I see why は has to be used. 世界の闇の中 is a new analogy being raised, so it would have a が (replaced by さえ), while あなた isn't new information, so it takes は. However, は/が aside, how else would some examples not make good sense?

Comment: (noun)さえ can be from (noun) が/を + さえ, so  君さえ止められない人間 can technically be interpreted both ways. But it's more natural to take 君 as the object because you'd say 君でさえ otherwise. On the other hand, it's rather unnatural to interpret 猿さえ解ける as "you can solve even monkeys", which itself is unnatural.

Comment: @user4092 thank you. So from what I gather, given that "questions can solve even monkeys" is unnatural, 猿さえ解ける is understood to mean 猿でさえ解ける. However it seems that in a situation where both meanings are possible, whether さえ or でさえ is used matters.

Answer (score 1):

O: 君でさえ止められない人間を見たことがない。I've never seen someone who**m** even you couldn't stop
O: 犯人でさえ人情がありますよ。世の悪党でさえ輝くことができる。
こんなかんじですか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。いいえ、類推の文章ですから、悪党じゃありません。「闇は悪いかんじがあるだけではなく、美のかんじもある」というふうかんじです。

Comment: それだったら接続詞が必要な感じがするけどね。「犯人でさえ人情がありますよ。つまり（そして、同様に）世界の闇でも輝くことができるということさ。」 こういうことかな?

Comment: そうなんですか。じゃ、接続詞があれば「でさえ」のほうがいいかもしれません。「世界の闇でも」-> 「世界の闇でさえ」ですから。