# How to say [even for somebody] vs just [for somebody]

Tags: word-choice, phrases, particle-も, particle-さえ

> これは私に難しい。
> This is difficult for me.

I want to say
[This it is difficult **EVEN** for me.]

The closest way to say it that I could find is using とっても [totte-mo], but for my understanding this word is not [even], it is [very]. As far as I understand it, it modifies the adjective [difficult] to [very difficult], but I want to modify the person to whom it is difficult.

> これは私にとっても難しい。
> This is VERY difficult to me.

As far as I understand every word which ends with も[mo] means [too][as well], but I want to say the meaning, that when it is difficult even for me, then you have no chance at all and therefore it makes no sense for you to try it at all. For you it will be a waste of time.

It is like: if even he can not do it, than you will 100% never do it. It is hard **even for him**.

**Question:**
What pattern should be used to modify the person, marked by に[ni], which is [to whom][for whom]? What general pattern is used to emphasize [even for someone][even for somebody][even for me/him/her/them/...]

---

**Update**

Downthere was a long way to final simple solution which is

> これは私**に**難しい。
> This is difficult for me.
>
> これは私**にでさえ**難しい。
> This is difficult **even** for me.

It's simple like that.
Just add でさえ after に and we get [even for somebody] instead of plain [for somebody].

Source: [Difference between さえ、でさえ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36397/)

Huge thanks to @henreetee for support!

Comment: The difference between にとって + も and に + とっても would one of intonation. They look the same written out, but they wouldn't sound the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there are numerous ways to express "even" in Japanese, so see the link at the bottom titled「ですら・でも…」if you would like to see an excellent explanation of those.

Second, to your example specifically, I think you are possibly confusing （にとって）+ the particle も; and the particle に+（とっても）.

The X+にとって construction means "to/for X" (e.g. 私にとって to/for me, 日本人にとって to/for Japanese people).

Correspondingly, the phrase X+にとって+も **can** be used to mean "even for X". Similarly to your example:

> 敬語は日本人にとっても難しい。
>
> Formal language is difficult even for Japanese people.
>
> (lit. Formal language is difficult for Japanese people, too).

Taking your example sentence:

> これは私にとっても難しい。can be understood as
>
> This is difficult **even** for me. OR
>
> This is difficult for me, **too**. OR
>
> This is, to me, **really** difficult. (though, I would say it would be clearer to say これは私に**は**とっても難しい if you wanted to convey this meaning)

Which one it would be would depend on what has already been said, what is mutually understood between the speaker and listener(s), and how it is said.

ーーー

EDIT: I should have mentioned さえ・すら as a possibility. さえ・すら are particles which mean 'even', and focuses the attention on the preceding item. The main difference with でも is that でも can be used to list numerous examples, but さえ and すら can only be used to show the *most powerful* example. But if でも is used only once (and it often is!), it can of course play the same function as さえ・すら.

For example:

> 日本語能力試験１級は日本人（でも・でさえ・ですら）難しい。can be understood as:
>
> Even for Japanese people, the JLPT Level 1 is difficult.

But this is arguably moving away from the original form of the question, and さえ・すら are a bit more complex in their usage, so instead of explaining in full, I will link [Maggie Sensei's page on さえ](http://maggiesensei.com/2015/03/28/how-to-use-%E3%81%95%E3%81%88sae/) and these Stack Exchange pages on it: [さえ: How to use it?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33409/%E3%81%95%E3%81%88-how-to-use-it) & [ですら・でも・さえ・だろう（と／が）。 Are there any differences?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/19784/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%82%89-%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82-%E3%81%95%E3%81%88-%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86-%E3%81%A8-%E3%81%8C-are-there-any-differences)

Comment: According to your answer there is no strick difference between [even for/to] vs [too/also/as well]. In all your 3 examples my brain sees [日本人にとっても] = [For Japanese too] not [even for Japanese], [私でも] = [me too] not [even for me], [日本人にも] = [Japanese too] not [even Japanese]. For me meaning of [even for/to] is inside [too/also/as well], but [even for] establishes hierarchy. [Even for Japanese] means their Japanese is much more expert, than mine. [For Japanese too] means we are the same. For my brain [I liked it too] is not [Even I liked it]. Your [私でも...] is [I liked it too] but not [Even I]

Comment: [It is clear to me too] = [I understand it as you. We just both understand it]. But [It is clear even to me] = [The idea is so simple, that even a kid can understand it]. [It is unclear to me too] = [I can not understand it as you. We just both can not get it.]. But [It is unclear even to me] = [You need PhD to understand it, and if you are just a kid for you it will be rocket science]. That how important [even for me] vs [me too], that's why I feel bad in using [にとっても] [for me too] or [でも] [me too].

Comment: You aren’t wrong that 日本人にとっても could be understood to mean “for Japanese people too”, but the point is that ても/でも constructions can be ambiguous like this. For instance, それは私にとっても良い。is (more often than not) going to be translated as “That is good for me too”, but perhaps you do want to say “that is good, even for me”, and you could express using the same words. It is the context of what has already been said, what is mutually understood, and how things are said that will inform which translation is best.

Comment: In any case, have edited my original post to include a brief section of さえ/すら, which might be more "definitively" unambiguous in expressing "even". I hope that that helps :)

Comment: I followed your link to Maggie and ... there is だって [datte] used as particle. When it is used as conj it is [Cause, ...], but when it is as particle... Might this be the thing I was looking for? What about 私にだって. Is it 100% [Even for/to me] or this is also has some [me too] meaning?

Comment: だって can work as "even", as you say, but it can also have "me too" connotation... 私だって日本に行きたい。is most likely to be understood as "I want to go to Japan, too", I think.

Comment: Oh, my god. No happy for me. If [私だって日本に行きたい。] = [I want to go to Japan too], then my initial question is still active. I want to find the way to say [Even i want to go to Japan, even me] = means [Everybody wanted to go to Japan, but I did not. But suddenly something happened, that even me, despite absence of initial desire, now wants to go to Japan].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95302/discussion-between-henreetee-and-tchibi-kun).

Comment: I've finally found what @henreetee wanted to explain me about using [sae] https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36397/ And the final solution is これは私にでさえ難しい。 [ni-de-sae] = [even for somebody]

Comment: I do appriciate your correction of my question about [When did we last time saw the sun?], but after your correction I had feeling, that this is not me! I would love to accept some mistakes corrections, but I just do not know how to accept them and not allow to kill my voice. Editing is a great help, but I just do not want you to speak instead of me. Please, understand my feelings right. And take my apologize if my rejection might hurt you. I really appriciate your intention to make my text better!

Comment: They are merely suggestions; you don’t have to accept them!

Comment: I really appreciate. I just do not know how accept some of them and deny some of them. I wanted to remeber mistakes and correct it by hand, but when I rejected, now I do not have access to your version and therefore do not know what parts it would be really great to fix. Terrible sorry, that it happened that way.